# Does the use of imagery to refer to reviewed copyright material count as fair dealing?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, fair-dealing

Under copyright, as I understand it, the use of images (and other media) can occur without permission in the case of criticism and review. However, sites such as [TierMaker](https://tiermaker.com/) uses images to represent what you are reviewing. To what extent is this allowed? For example, would [this](https://tiermaker.com/create/harry-potter-movies-tier-list-417381) tier list of Harry Potter movies fall under fair dealing when they aren't reviewing the movie covers, but the movies themselves?

To confirm, I pose this in the context of UK copyright law, and specifically in the case of the use of imagery to represent material. (e.g one could argue that the imagery is superfluous in the reference of the critiques material, making it not fair dealing)

Comment: You could make this a better question by changing your title to ask about whatever activity TierMaker does that you are questioning the legality of; right now the headline is just a question about some proprietary software most people on this site have never heard of.

Comment: @michael I have done so; thanks

Comment: Another way to put this, then, is "Does UK law have an analog of fair use?", which I suspect has been asked and answered here.

Comment: @user6726 It does; but this question doesn't generalise that far; I don't feel I have the expertise or knowledge to deduce the answer this question asks (which is the use of copyrighted images to refer to something (which would itself fall under fair use)) from a generic answer as to what constitutes fair use in the UK.

Comment: That site only has a gmail address as their contact. So guess in which country they are based.. The fact that you've exemplified their activity with a Harry Potter cover art is a lot *less* relevant. Given how their TOS is phrased, I suspect they are US based https://tiermaker.com/guidelines/terms-of-use/ In fact, the latter even has an actual address... in the US, at the end.